# In Wordpress, can the_tags be modified to return tags in natural sort (natsort) order?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a wordpress 3.4.2, and using tags with numbers in the name to associate with posts.

Specifically:
'0-5', '6-10', '11-15', '16-20', and '21-25' are my tags.

If the above tags are associated with the post, I'd like to show them in natsort order (http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) , but instead its coming back in alphabetical order, like this:

0-5, 11-15, 16-20, 21-25, **6-10**

meaning that 6-10 will show up after 11-15, because '6' comes after '1'.

Here's the wordpress call I'm using to bring back the tags:

```
<?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="post-footer-label">' . __('Ranges: ', 'blankslate' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span>" ) ?>
```

Does anyone know how I would modify that, or what extra function should I write, so that I can get back the tags in the order I prefer?

Answer (score 0):

Where [the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_tags) displays the tags for the current post, [get_the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) returns them as an array. You can then sort them and display them as needed.

In your case, you could use something like this, which uses [strnatcmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php):

```
<?php
    function compare_tags_naturally($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a->name, $b->name);
    }

    $unsorted_tags = get_the_tags();
    $tags = usort($unsorted_tags, 'compare_tags_naturally');

    $links = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $links[] = '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }

    echo '<span class="tag-links"><span class="post-footer-label">' . __('Ranges: ', 'blankslate' ) . '</span>';
    echo implode(', ', $links);
    echo '</span>';

?>
```

If you wanted this sorting functionality to automatically apply to everywhere [the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_tags) is used, you could wrap the relevant code above in a plugin, and add a [Wordpress Filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) on "the_tags".

Unfortunately, there is currently no official documentation on exactly how to do that, although there is [documentation on the "the_tags" filter on a site that automatically extracts references to various hooks from the Wordpress source code](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/the_tags).